# sin and cosine in brackets??

Tags: notation, matrix-equations, functional-calculus

What does it mean to have brackets used like this?? Also on the other side, the same representation is used for $x-x'$ and $g(x)$. Where can I read more about this?

> $$[\sin\theta_i, \cos\theta_i] = [(x - x'), g(x)] / \sqrt{(x - x')^2 + [g(x)]^2}$$

Comment: It is almost certainly supposed to be a vector with those two numbers as components, but there isn't enough context to be 100% sure.

Comment: Where are you seeing this notation?  Is it in a book?  which book?  Is it being used by an instructor? in which course?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like vector notation, a way to write two equations in one line.  There is one equation for each of the two components of the vectors:
\begin{align}
\sin \theta_i &= \frac{x-x’}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+[g(x)]^2}} \\
\cos \theta_i &= \frac{g(x)}{\sqrt{(x-x')^2+[g(x)]^2}} \\
\end{align}

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but I updated the answer to explicitly list both equations in full.